# Angular to update UI from the child component reflect the value to the parent component

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I, am using *IF-else statement in angular 5. If the authorization value is true the template 2 should render if not template 1 should render. Here is the code

```
<div *ngIf="authorized; then picUrl else login"></div>

                <ng-template #login>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-color-text--white" style="background: #033342" (click)="openDialog()">Login</button>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #picUrl>
                    <img src="{{_loginVM.profilePic}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="profile pic">
                </ng-template>
```

Calling the social component

```
<social></social>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    public authorized: boolean = false;
}
```

**Social component.ts**

```
import { AppComponent} from '../app/app.component'

    export class SocialComponent {
        private _appComponent: AppComponent;
        constructor(private socialAuthService: AuthService, appComponent: AppComponent,
            public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SignInSignUpDialogHomeComponent>) {
            this._appComponent = appComponent;
        }
     public socialSignIn(socialPlatform: string) {
            let socialPlatformProvider: any;
            if (socialPlatform == "facebook") {
                socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
            } else if (socialPlatform == "google") {
                socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
            }

            this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
                (userData) => {
                    if (userData != null) {
                        this._appComponent.authorized = true;
                        this._appComponent._loginVM.profilePic = userData.image;
                        this.dialogRef.close();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

After the successfully login the value is updated as `this._appComponent.authorized = true;`. The value is not reflected to the UI/UX.

I found some references from here
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

I, tried with `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`. But no know how to subscribe to the UI data bind. Is, this is the way I, have to do?. Can't I do directly to the component variable?

Comment: your social component is children of app component right ? if so then you can use @Output event emitter after successful login and subscribe it in app component to change the `authorized` value to true/false

Comment: Using Observable Subject/BehaviourSubject would also solve your purpose.

Comment: It is not common practice to inject a component within another component as you have done. Rather, use a service to share data between multiple components. I have a blog post about this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/ along with a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.html

```
<div *ngIf="authorized; then picUrl else login"></div>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.authorized= this.authService.isLoggedIn;
}
```

service.ts

```
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.currentUser != null; //you can decide to return true or false
 }
get currentuser(): user{
  let user = localstorage.getitem('details')
return user;
}
```