# Data sharing between component with data servive not working in angular 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I, am using data service to share the data between the component. However, this seems not working for me.

Got the reference from here

[Angular to update UI from the child component reflect the value to the parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144872/angular-to-update-ui-from-the-child-component-reflect-the-value-to-the-parent-co/49146498#49146498)
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

I tried the same logic as above but seems to not work for me.

Here is the html binding for the angular material

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="commonViewModel.showProgressBar()"></mat-progress-bar>
```

**Parent component**

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor(public commonViewModel: CommonViewModel) {    }
ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoding();
    }
isLoding() {
        console.log("app=" + this.commonViewModel.showProgressBar());
        return this.commonViewModel.showProgressBar();
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export class HomeComponent {
    private GetHomeItemUrl: string = "Home/GetHomeItem";
    private _homeItemService: GenericHttpClientService;
    constructor(public commonViewModel: CommonViewModel) {
        this.getHomeItemHttpCall();
    }

    private getHomeItemHttpCall(): void {

        this.commonViewModel.setProgressBarShow = true;
        this._homeItemService.GenericHttpGet<GenericResponseObject<HomeViewModel>>(this.GetHomeItemUrl).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.isSuccess) {
                this.commonViewModel.setProgressBarShow = false;
                console.log("home=" +this.commonViewModel.showProgressBar());
            }

        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

This is my service class which hold the value as true and false

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonViewModel {
    progressBarShow: boolean = true;

    public showProgressBar(): boolean {
        return this.getProgressBarShow;
    }

    set setProgressBarShow(flag: boolean) {
        this.progressBarShow = flag;
    }
    get getProgressBarShow(): boolean {
        return this.progressBarShow;
    }
}
```

The console output

[image: console input]

In the console I,can see the output as **True** and **False**. But the app never hides as I can see the app component value is always **true**

Where I, am doing mistake. Can please someone let me know. I, dont want to use Input and Output to share the data.

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that your parent component and your child component are being injected with two different instances of the service, depending on where you "provide" it. Try providing it from your app module.

Also, if the child is a direct child of the parent, you don't need the service, you can have an EventEmitter (an @Output) in child, and communicate through that.

See the documentation at https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: It is not direct of parent

Answer (score 0):

I think, that GSSWain's answer must be work. If not, try use a getter

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-progress-bar>

get isLoading(){
    return this.commonViewModel.showProgressBar();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. I, have added console output please have a look. The this.commonViewModel.showProgressBar() from isLoding() method always return True as the value in false in the highlighted pic